# I want to update my table columns based on another one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one database that I've created a year ago but then I've created a new one recently and added some new columns into tables. I want to update my ex database with new schema without losing my data. I just want to update missing columns that I've created later on.

For example:

This one is the old one without 'NTOTAL', 'IDPRODUCT'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`alter table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html).  Something like:

```
alter table oldone add column ntotal int;
```

The column will be assigned the default value (`NULL`).  By default it goes at the end (i.e. when you do `select *` it is last).  MySQL allows you to control the position of the column using the `FIRST` or `AFTER` keywords.